# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-should-our-domain-name-be).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Answer (score 9):

Mind your speech? - Speak your mind!

Comment: I like the cleverness of it. +1!

Answer (score 8):

Helping you get the words out.

Answer (score 5):

Elevator Pitch

> English has its tricky points. Don't ask someone to explain - ask everyone!

Tagline/Motto

> Good advice in English.
>
> Say what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Two taglines:

**Proper words in their proper places.**

Adapted from a Jonathan Swift quote:

> Proper words in their proper places make the true definition of style

**Words: the most powerful drug used by mankind.**

Adapted from a Rudyard Kipling quote:

> Words are, of course, the most powerful drug used by mankind.

Answer (score 3):

Elevator pitch

> The community that democratically with rationale solves the quest for better English.

Tagline

> Officializing English. Or wait, is it officialise?

Motto

> English we think!

Answer (score 3):

How about "Make every word count"?

Answer (score 2):

Related questions which might be consulted when answering (sorry, too many for a comment):

- [What questions are on-topic and off-topic here?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-off-topic-here)
- [Is this site for “English as a second language”?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-this-site-for-english-as-a-second-language)
- [This is not a site for peeving](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/this-is-not-a-site-for-peeving),
- [Who's the audience; How to promote?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/whos-the-audience-how-to-promote)
- [Do we need a 'Site Manifesto'?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/do-we-need-a-site-manifesto)
- [How to answer questions about acceptability](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322/how-to-answer-questions-about-acceptability)

*Community wiki so that others can add/remove as desired*

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The English source you will always go to.</strike> The source for English knowledge to which you will always go.

Answer (score 1):

Motto, perhaps?

> We know irony.

Answer (score 1):

Tagline (inspired by @Ralph):

> In English we trust.

[[[wp:In God We Trust](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/In_God_We_Trust)]]

Answer (score 0):

**What's the good word?**

Answer (score 0):

Needs improvement, but something along the lines of "*English <s>on the line</s> online*".

> Keyboard some English.

Answer (score -3):

Me no speaky English

Comment: Rofl!!!!!!!!!15

Comment: Oh, God, make it stop!! HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!